# DynamoDB tables's RCU/WCU is not increasing even after throttle errors

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have created a DynamoDB table with capacity mode `On-demand`.

I am performing a few queries on the global secondary index of the table which give me errors:
`An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the Query operation (reached max retries: 2): Throughput exceeds the current capacity for one or more global secondary indexes. DynamoDB is automatically scaling your index so please try again shortly`

My request is failed which is OK but how can I confirm if my table's capacity RCU/WCU increased or not? I am not able to see anything in cloud watch as well.

Comment: When you say "a few queries", how many are we talking? A table or GSI on creation or move to on-demand mode can support at minimum 12,000 reads per second.

Answer (score 1):

Capacity is opaque in the pay-per-use [On-Demand mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand). On-Demand mode meters throughput with [Request Units (WRU/RRU)](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/), which are measured the same as the equivalent [Capacity Units (WCU/RCU)](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) of the pay-per-hour [Provisioned Throughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html) mode, for which the provisioned table capacity is visible (e.g. using the `describe-table` API).

On-Demand mode scales behind the scenes based on [previous peak traffic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.PeakTraffic), allocating 2x previous peak traffic.  Throttling should only occur if traffic increases more than double the peak within 30 minutes:

> If you need more than double your previous peak on table, DynamoDB automatically allocates more capacity as your traffic volume increases to help ensure that your workload does not experience throttling. However, throttling can occur if you exceed double your previous peak within 30 minutes.